# $q not returning the promise that I've sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue that is taking out my patience. My promises started not working and I think it maybe a version issue for me. I've made this code several times and it worked like a charm:

```
angular.module('blogApp')
  .factory('person', function ($http, $q) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/pessoas';

    return {
      getPeople: function() {
      var d = $q.defer();

      $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
          d.resolve(data);
        });
      return d.promise;
    }
});
```

my controller:

```
angular.module('blogApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, person) {        
   $scope.people = person.getPeople();
 });
```

I've logged person.getPeople() and its showing the deffered object without resolve.

What did I miss?
Thanks!

Comment: $http call doesn't return nothing but a promise, never the data it retrieves.

Comment: exactly, this is why i'm using $q, to resolve these promises before associating with the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are affecting a promise to your `people` variable.
Whether it is resolved or not is not part of the issue. 
What you want is to affect the **result** of the http call, not a promise.

Here an example:

```
angular.module('blogApp')
  .factory('person', function ($http, $q) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/pessoas';

    return {
      getPeople: function() {
         return $http.get(url);
    }
});

angular.module('blogApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, person) {        
   person.getPeople()
       .then(function(data){
             $scope.people = data; 
        }
 });
```

Comment: my issue is using .then() on the controller. seems like the solution that deferring functions came to resolve with a simple function call make asynchronous association. I don't see the advantage of using .then() when I could use the success() from the $http itself. my point is to exploit the factory the most while making the controller as thin as possible.

Comment: `success` doesn't return a promise. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Use `resolve` property of `$routeProvider` if you want a synchronous call.